# how i can show debug log user

Tags: apex, login-errors, debug

> I want to see debug log in salesforce,but when i go to debug log and
>   click on on user there is no user in look up to select. Any one can
>   help me.

Answer (score 4):

When you first click the User lookup field it only shows recently viewed Users, you need to search for a User, in your case searching for 'Riaz' should show your account.

Comment: more detailed info can be found in http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforcecom-debug-logs/